# How to send a text with button(without text field)? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, text

I want to set a couple of button which will send some text I assigned, how can I send a text without using a textfield area? Below code contains an icon button and a texfield area with button void part is the function I use,

I want to send a specific name when hit the icon button for login(for example testuser1), or any username can be send by textfield area.

```
children: <Widget>[
         new ListTile(
           title: new Row(
             children: <Widget>[IconButton(
               icon: Icon(Icons.stars),
               iconSize: 40,
               onPressed: () {setState(() {
                 saveName();
               });
               },
             ),
               Text('Test User Entry')
             ],
           )
         ),
         new ListTile(
           title: new TextField(
             obscureText: false,
             controller: _controller,
             decoration: InputDecoration(
               labelText: 'Username',
             ),
           ),
         ),
         new ListTile(
           title: new RaisedButton(
               child: new Text("Send"),
               onPressed:(){setState(() {
                 saveName();
               });
               }),
         )
       ],
     ),
   );
 }
 void saveName() {
   String name = _controller.text;
   saveNamedPreference(name).then((bool committed) {
     Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(MyHomePage.routeName);
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: You want to send a string to a new route on button pressed using `pushReplacementNamed`?

Comment: Yes, for example if I have a username I can get it in text field then push to submit button to get in, but if I don't have one I just click to icon button(named Test User Entry) then a string which fixed testuser1 or something set the state of "name" parameter.

Comment: Are you trying to send static data to next page?

Comment: yes actually, that is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it with a messy way(I though) like this;

```
new ListTile(
            title: new IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.trending_up),
                iconSize: 40,
                onPressed: () {setState(() {
                  String name = "NewNameValue";
                  saveNamedPreference(name).then((bool committed) {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(MyHomePage.routeName);
                  });
                });
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure If I understood you correctly, if you don't want textfield to be seen, you can make it invisible.

Comment: I don't want to text field at all for icon button. Actually I want to send a fixed word when pressed to icon button that's all. text field area and the button belngs to it will be optional to send another name.